# CronJob on FTP Server on PHP File

Tags: php, cron, jobs, cron-task

I have access on ftp server - host / user / password.

I want to run a php file from that server - specific time (every 3 days for example)

How can i make a cron job if i am on windows, and have access on ftp server?
Only want to run an existing php file from that ftp server every 3 days.

Thank you..

Comment: define "having access to the ftp server". Can you run `crontab -e`, or access  to the system-wide `/etc/crontab` file? In case of the latter: don't trust that host

Comment: FTP stands for `File transfer protocol`. There's no "running" or "scheduling" implied or stated within that acronym. That being said, windows can schedule tasks and part of that schedule can be to connect to an FTP, download a PHP file and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run it through FTP. You'll need SSH access and permissions to run crontab (as mentioned by @Elias Van Ootegem)